# Enabling GC log in java web application on tomcat

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a java web application running on Tomcat(running as service),
I want to enable GC logging. 
In windows command line in java/bin/ folder I am running the following command

```
java -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:C:/Users/aa/Desktop/gc.log
```

The log is created, but it contains corrupted data, and the log is not updating

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.171-b11) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_171-b11), built on Mar 28 2018 16:06:12 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
Memory: 4k page, physical 16655948k(3946040k free), swap 39679116k(5477732k free)
CommandLine flags: -XX:InitialHeapSize=266495168 -XX:MaxHeapSize=4263922688 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:-UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation -XX:+UseParallelGC 
Heap
PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 3932K [0x000000076b400000, 0x0000000770900000, 0x00000007c0000000)
eden space 65536K, 6% used [0x000000076b400000,0x000000076b7d7240,0x000000076f400000)
from space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076fe80000,0x000000076fe80000,0x0000000770900000)
to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076f400000,0x000000076f400000,0x000000076fe80000)
ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 0K [0x00000006c1c00000, 0x00000006cc700000, 0x000000076b400000)
object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c1c00000,0x00000006c1c00000,0x00000006cc700000)
Metaspace       used 2909K, capacity 4480K, committed 4480K, reserved 1056768K
class space    used 329K, capacity 384K, committed 384K, reserved 1048576K
```

But when I am setting

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:C:/Users/aa/Desktop/gc.log
```

this configuration in eclipse VM arguments it works. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add those flags to the `JAVA_OPTS` field in the `setenv.bat` file in the Tomcat /bin directory.

Does the Tomcat process has write access to the GC Log folder?
When logs are written they should not be corrupted. You can check a log quickly with gceasy.io.

The log updates only when GC is running. This may be just once in a longer period of time, depending on your application and the GC algorithm.

Hint: Don´t forget to activate log rotation, otherwise you may run out of storage.